# If the data getting from the redux store is empty display message showing no data found otherwise show the data with loader

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component in which i want to show my data in list form and whenever the data is empty i want to give the message that no data found, but what is happening is even when the data is there in the list and i am checking
if(data.length === 0){
no data found
}
this if condition is inside a function and i am calling that function in render method whenever i refresh the page before rendering the list of data it shows no data found and then the data is shown. I want to avoid showing no data found on refresh when data is available.

Answer (score 0):

Either use
`data.length===0?(<p>No data fount<p>):(<Listcomponent />)`
in the render function
or  `return data.length===0?(<p>No data fount<p>):(<Listcomponent />)`
in you function